# C Programing Filename is in chinese symbols

Tags: c, strftime, time.h

I am trying to modify some source code as i need to create a filename based on the date however the filename is being created with chinese symbols. I am compiling using nmake for visual studio and unicode.

I am not sure whether this is a code issue or a compiler problem.

Code Extract:

```
   struct tm * timeinfo;
    struct tm *__cdecl localtime(const time_t *t);
    TCHAR buffer[80];
    time_t rawtime;
    rawtime = time(NULL);
    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d%m%Y%H%M%S", timeinfo);
    prd->command[i] = '\0';

    LPTSTR t;
    for (t = buffer; *t; t++) {
        if ((*t != '<') && (*t != '>') && (*t != '\"') &&
            (*t != '|') && (*t != '/') && (*t != '\\') &&
            (*t != ':'))
            prd->command[i++] = *t;
    }
    //lstrcat(prd->command, buffer);
    i = lstrlen(prd->command);
```

Well after some investigation prompted by the possible duplicate, i now have working code. I had already expected and investigated it was to do with the TCHAR conversion, but not come up with an answer. I did some more investigation on this and came across wcsftime. This seems to have worked and means i do not need to make other modifications to get the code to work and compiles fine in VS2013.

Working code:

```
        struct tm * timeinfo;
    struct tm *__cdecl localtime(const time_t *t);
    wchar_t buffer[80];
    time_t rawtime;
    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    wcsftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), L"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S", timeinfo);
    prd->command[i] = '\0';
    lstrcat(prd->command, buffer);
    i = lstrlen(prd->command);
    s++;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::string to LPCTSTR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711124/stdstring-to-lpctstr)

Comment: I don't recommend TCHAR.  Use Unicode and `wchar_t` exclusively, when calling Win32 API.  You are getting [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).